# Catch clicks on file links (as opposed to page links) in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to add an event to my users clicking on file links (as opposed to links to internal or external pages).  Is there a simple way to just get file links  with a jquery selector?  Or, do you think it's better to put a class on my file links and just select on the basis of that class?

thanks, max

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$` to get links having file extension:

```
$('a[href$=".pdf"]')
```

You can replace the `.pdf` with whatever file extension you want.

Comment: Oooh... I'd never seen that one before. And here was me about to say you'd have to put classes on... :) That having been said I still think I'd advocate putting a class on since its much easier, especially if you have lots of different file types, etc. :)

Comment: ah yeah, that's cool.  I guess that's the 'ends-with' selector?  That is nice but after a bit of thought i'm going with putting classes on the links as it's more explicit.  cheers tho :) max

Comment: @Max Williams: Yes it is end with selector and you are welcome :)